# Is It "Bad Form" To Use A Map Function That Sends An Email In A Java Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use Java Streams to make the sequential processing of a list of customers run in parallel.  This is a short-term band-aid to a problem that we are solving as part of re-architecting our entire system.

What I am starting with is a `List<Customer> Customers` structure that contains the customer contact information and all the relevant transaction data.  Conceptually, the code I am replacing looks like:

```
long emailsSent = 0;
List<Customer> customers = methodLoadingAllrelevantData();
for (Customer customer: customers) {
    boolean isEmailSent = sendEmail(customer);
    if (isEmailSent) {
        emailsSent++;
    }
}
```

The `sendMail(customer)` function:

1. Determines if an email should be sent
2. Formats the email
3. Attempts to send the email
4. Returns true if the email was sent successfully

Not great code, but I am just trying to get some more speed from the existing code, not trying to make it better.  The method and all its calls are 100-percent thread-safe.

I put it in the following stream structure:

```
ForkJoinPool limitedParallelThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads);
emailsSent = limitedParallelThreadPool.submit( () ->
    customers.stream().parallel()
        .map(this::_emailCustomer)
        .filter(b -> b == true).count()
).get();
```

This does work as expected, returning the same data as the sequential version.

My questions are: because the purpose of my method is to generates an email, is it poor practice for me to use a `map` function?  Is there a better answer?  I am, in effect, mapping a Customer to a boolean, but part of this mapping requires the process to trigger an email.

I was originally trying to use a `forEach()`operator, but I could not figure out how to get the count without adding state information to the `sendMail` function, which interferes with it being thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

> Returns true if the email was sent successfully

It wouldn't be the worst idea to take advantage of the fact that your `_emailCustomer` method returns a `boolean`, so you can use `Stream#filter` instead of a combination of both `Stream#map` and `Stream#filter`:

```
customers.parallelStream()
         .filter(this::_emailCustomer)
         .count()
```

To answer your question, though, it would depend on the use-case whether or not `Stream#map` is the correct intermediate operation to use. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) of `Stream#map`, the `Function` argument that the method accepts must be:

> a [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) function to apply to each element

If your `_emailCustomer` method is either interfering or stateful, then I would refrain from calling it within `Stream#map`, especially in a parallel context.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob G, for this reply.  The function actually is non-interfering and stateless: it does not update any persistent data and can be run over and over, producing identical emails and results.  I had discussed using the filter operation with my colleagues, but the general consensus was that was more obfuscating than calling the process out as a mapping between a Customer and a boolean result.  But that is just opinion.

Comment: Then it looks like you’ve answered your own question :)

Comment: @Jacob G. Is it really guaranteed by stream API that filter will be called for each `Customer` in the list? What if the list contains the same instance of `Customer` twice? Will `filter` be called on that instance once or twice? And if it does, will the behavior stay the same with future versions of JDK.

Comment: @tsolakp Yes, `Stream#filter` will be called for each element in the stream even if duplicates exist (assuming no call to `Stream#distinct` was made previously). So even if the same element exists twice in the stream, then `Stream#filter` will be called twice. I would expect the behavior to be maintained with future versions of the JDK, as backwards compatibility is one of Java's core ideals.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care in which order those emails are getting sent, I'd say you kind of OK in this example. It's just that you are relying on side-effects of the `map` intermediate operation and potentially that can bite you. For example this:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4)
      .map(x -> x + 1)
      .count();
```

will not execute the `map` at all (starting with java-9), since all you want is `count` and `map` will not change the final count. Your example is safe from that since you are filtering, thus the final count is not known, thus `map` has to be executed. As said, for a parallel environment there is no guarantee about the order in which `map` will be executed.

It's a pity though that your `sendEmail` returns something at all, all the email services I wrote were more like a event thing - fire and forget; but I can't tell your exact scenario needed.

Think about the fact that your `map` operation will block, until you get a response back and that might trigger this part of the documentation that you need to look at:

> A ForkJoinPool is constructed with a given target parallelism level; by default, equal to the number of available processors. The pool attempts to maintain enough active (or available) threads by dynamically adding, suspending, or resuming internal worker threads, even if some tasks are stalled waiting to join others

Comment: Thank you, Eugene.  I will keep your comments in mind as my team re-engineers this nightmare.